# How can I see each of tables from database in R?

Tags: r

For example, under "nycflights13" database, there are many tables including flights and weather, etc.

```
library(nycflights13)
```

After writing above, how I can see about actual information of the tables like table names, structures in case of that I don't know any table names.

`head(nycflights13)` or `str(nycflights13)` do not work.

Comment: Do you mean datasets within the package?

Comment: `data()` is a start.

Comment: since you have it loaded (ie, in the `search()` path), `ls('package:nycflights13')` would also work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see datasets within a package you can simply use the `data` function and specify the package of interest.

```
data(package='nycflights13')
```

after which you can use `str` to see the structures.

Answer (score 3):

```
data(package='nycflights13')
```

gives you what tables are available.

```
Data sets in package ‘nycflights13’:

    airlines                Airline names.
    airports                Airport metadata
    flights                 Flights data
    planes                  Plane metadata.
    weather                 Hourly weather data
```

And then you can head any specific table:

```
head(airlines)
```